# What happens if I stay with Nurse Jenny in the Asylum?

Tags: the-darkness-2

At one point near the end of the game, you have to choose a reality: either one in which you are mentally ill and riddled with hallucinations, or one in which the Darkness is trying to trick you.

[image: Choices, choices.]

My (obvious) choice was to throw myself off the Asylum roof, which seems to have been

> the *correct* choice. As you're falling, the illusion fades, and the Darkness voices its displeasure. You then go to hell and a bunch of stuff happens. Go figure.

What would have happened if I'd chosen the "stay with Jenny" option instead?

Comment: Just do new game plus and pick the Jenny option. Although the statement keen hall made is true. It just ends. But I like to say the obviously true ending is jumping off, that just seems true to Estacados personality.

Comment: You don't unlock the game completion achievement if you stay with her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stay with Jenny, you dance to some music in the Asylum and the credits roll. After that, the game goes back to the main menu.

I did like you and went for the "this isn't real" option and threw myself off the roof.

Comment: Well, I regret nothing.

Comment: Video is dead :(